# Why is the event.key and event.keyCode undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I'm creating a lightning flow component and I want to capture key strokes to automatically control formatting. i.e. all numbers or all letters or insert '-' for tax id's. However when the function is called the event.key parameters all seem to be undefined? What am I missing

Component .cmp

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="num" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="rdText" type="string" default=""/>
    <div>
        <lightning:input type="text" label="Number: " value="{!v.num}" 
          onkeydown="{!c.rdKeyDown}" onkeyup="{!c.rdKeyUp}" onkeypress="{!c.rdKeyPress}" onchange="{!c.rdTextChanged}"/>
          Code Notes: {!v.rdText}
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller .js

```
({
    rdKeyDown : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(event.key + " Key Down!");
        component.set('v.rdText', event.key + 'Key Down!');
    },
    rdKeyUp : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(event.key + " Key Up!");
        component.set('v.rdText', event.key + ' Key Up!');
    },
    rdKeyPress : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(event.key + " Key Pressed!");
        component.set('v.rdText', event.key + ' Key Pressed!');
    },
    rdTextChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("Text Changed!");
        component.set('v.rdText', 'Text Changed!');
    }
})
```

Comment: Check answer posted [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/200803)

Comment: Thanks @Shamina. Felt like by everything I read and looked at, it should've worked but didn't. Simply moving the events to a wrapper element made it work as expected. Sincerely appreciate the help.